# Visual Studio Code not recognize the term "php" as a command

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, cmd, terminal

In my Windows terminal (cmd), the **php -v** command return the version of installed PHP in my computer. But when I type it at Visual Studio Code (version 1.63.2) terminal, it gives me the error below:

> php : The term 'php' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
> if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - php -v
> - ```
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (php:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>   ```

Note that the environment variable is already set.
Any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

VSC is running powershell as terminal, configure it to use CMD
in your user's file->preferences->settings add:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows":"cmd.exe"
```

Comment: But even in the powershell terminal, php -v return me the version of my installed PHP. Also, the default terminal used by VSC is already C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe

Comment: Have you set the environment variable AFTER running VSC? If so, restart VSC.

Comment: Yes, environment variable is set, and I've already restarted VSC.

Comment: Are yoiu running VSC as a different user (ex: administrator)? If so check your path is set system-wide and not just user-wide

Comment: Yes, I have different user and the path is set using system-wide. Maybe I should try to add user-wide.

Comment: I added both system and user path but still not working.

Comment: Try running the prompt as the user running VSC and see if php starts

Comment: Thank you for your time trying to help me

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I solved the problem by deleting (killing) the already created profile in the VSC terminal (see the below figure) and adding a new one. Restarting VSC is not enough. You have to delete or kill the terminal profile and re-create it again by choosing PowerShell or command prompt or whatever you want according to your system.

**Delete profile**

[image]

**Create profile**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Click on settings icons -> Choose Settings**

[image: Choose Settings]

**In Searchbar type php -> select php from menu -> Then click on `Edit in settings.json`**

[image]

**Scroll Down to bottom and check `php.validate.executablePath` this**

[image]

**Add or update your php path here like this -**

[image]

**NOTE -**
You need to modify your php file path `C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.1.6` to  `C:\\laragon\\bin\\php\\php-8.1.6`

Comment: This directive is used by the builtin PHP extension to lint PHP code. It has nothing to do with the terminal, and if you use a better third-party PHP extension like DEVSENSE or PHP Intelephense it's highly recommended to disable the builtin extension anyway.